# Why `xclip .bashrc` takes much longer than system("xclip .bashrc") in ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, xclip

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'benchmark'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> puts Benchmark.measure { system "xclip .bashrc" }
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.008030)
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts Benchmark.measure { `xclip .bashrc` }
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 ( 33.215158)
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.0.0"
```

I have read alomost everything on the internet about various ways to call shell command from ruby script, but I just can't figure out why `` Kernel#` `` takes much much longer than `Kernel#system`.

**Update**:

`` Kernel#` `` is much slower only with `xclip`. All the other commands takes almost the same time.

Comment: @platzhirsch `xclip` output nothing to the standard output, it does not explain why `xclip` alone is much slower with backtick and the other command like `cat` works completely fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that `xclip` just takes a long time to terminate when you use backticks to shell out. This has to do with the selection. Without any selection provided through `-sel` it will default to `XA_PRIMARY` which is conventionally used to implement copying and pasting via the middle mouse button.

When you run

```
$ xclip text.txt
```

the content becomes available through `XA_PRIMARY` which means you can paste it through your middle mouse button or `$ xclip -o`. It starts to get weird when you execute it thorugh a shell out in Ruby:

```
ruby -e '`xclip text.txt`
```

It never really terminates if you do nothing. It terminates when you select someting in your X11 system, for instance in the console or everywhere else. Just selection, marking something with your mouse. If you do not, it will hang and/or timeout at some point.

The same behavior can be observed when you use the verbose mode:

```
$ xclip -verbose text.txt

Connected to X server.
Using UTF8_STRING.
Reading text.txt...
Waiting for selection requests, Control-C to quit
  Waiting for selection request number 1
```

The selection request, again, is served when you select something.

A good analysis tool for this is [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) (the `-f` option is for tracking forks, too)

```
$ strace -f ruby -e '`xclip text.txt`'

...
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\20\0\3\0\4\0\200\2INCR", 12}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 12
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "\1\0\f\0\0\0\0\0\235\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096,                                                                      0, NULL, NULL) = 32
recvfrom(3, 0x165e964, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvfrom(3, 0x165e964, 4096, 0, 0, 0)   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295
```

In the last line it hangs until a selection is made. `poll()` is used to wait for a file event at the file descriptor. It will terminate at some point, but 4,294,967,295 ms is rather long. It can be traced the same with with just `strace -f xclip text.txt`.

You can take a look at the file descriptors through `ls -l /proc/PID/fd`. The one with number 3 is the file descriptor where `xclip` waits for your selection.

What makes it so hard to debug is that if terminates instantly with `strace xclip text.txt`, but not with `strace -f text.txt`. The moment where you want to trace the fork it does not work anymore. That is the same problem you have with Ruby. It tries to trace the output, because `` Kernel#` `` wants to return the output. This has probably also to do with the ticket [#9 Not closing stdout when setting clipboard from stdin](http://sourceforge.net/p/xclip/bugs/9/).

This is my theory. The moment you shell out and want to follow the output of `xclip`, be it with Ruby to read from standard out, or `strace` to trace the forks, the standard output does not get closed until you make a selection.

This does not explain it very well, but it demonstrates that is does not have to do anything with Ruby. I will create a question which focuses on `xclip` only and not in the context of Ruby.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide more specifics, about what you are doing with xclip.  B/c (because) my ruby 1.9.3 using "echo hello" shows minimal difference.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'benchmark'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> puts Benchmark.measure {  `echo hello` }
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001471)
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts Benchmark.measure { system "echo hello" }
hello
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001598)
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"
```

Comment: I'm just trying to manipulate the Linux clipboard with xclip. `echo` is also fine on my system, it's just `xclip` that is much slower with backtick.

Comment: You might try reversing the Kernel#` and Kernel#system call order several times, and testing this a number of times.  You are probably looking at timing from xclip, rather than Ruby.

Comment: I've been stuck on this issue for hours, believe me, I have test this many many times, just now, I tested it on my friend's computer, the same result: `system "xclip file"` is super fast just like type it in the terminal then hit RET, `\`xclip file\`` takes dozens of seconds to finish and it gets slower when the file gets lager.

Comment: Sorry, but that is rather a comment and not an answer.